# Did Leopold Godowsky perform the entire 19th Century piano repertoire?

Tags: history, music

In 1897–98 the Polish-American pianist and composer Leopold Godowsky is reported to have performed the entire 19th century piano repertoire in a series of only 8 concerts. This is hardly imaginable or even possible.

Is this claim true? What pieces were played by him exactly?

[Web Archive of the Biography  from godowsky.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20060206110843/http://www.godowsky.com/Biography/bio.html):

> For the 1897-98 season he presented a series of eight programs surveying the entire 19th-century literature of the piano.

[Biographical book reference provided by the site](https://web.archive.org/web/20060207191721/http://www.godowsky.com/Biography/nicholas.html#book)

Comment: The linked web page seems to be by an author of the biography "Godowsky - The Pianists' Pianist". Is there a list of citations in the book?

Comment: This page has the authors then-current email address: https://web.archive.org/web/20060207191721/http://www.godowsky.com/Biography/nicholas.html

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have the book!

Comment: Thanks for the hint on the email address, will look here first.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) I found the actual claim from the (archived) web-site. It doesn't claim he played every possible piece written in the 19th Century, but that he merely "surveyed" it. Is this a misreading of the claim, or is there more to it?

Comment: Thanks! That is an interesting specification.  I would want to know what pieces were played to survey the 19th century music, it would be interesting to know what a giant like Godowsky would think as 'essential', if that would be the way to look at it.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is out of scope here. There is no notable claim you are doubtful about.